# Open link in chrome using inappbrowser phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, safari

Is there a way I can open a link from my phonegap app in chrome or safari, if available else in android browser.

Currently it opens in default android browser. I have been using this way:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the working, but this may help.
You can use `_blank` or `_new` options to make this work as:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
```

Or

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_new');
```